# "...demands of us that we not lose sight..."

Tags: grammar

> What are those weighty moral and intellectual demands? For one thing, I think the Holocaust demands of us **that we not lose sight** of the fact that it was not just another tragedy in war-torn Europe amidst clashing nationalisms.
>
> Source: [LA Review of Books](http://lareviewofbooks.org/essay/hitler-continued-afterword-updated-edition-explaining-hitler-search-origins-evil)

I have a question regarding the form of the subordinate clause "that we not lose sight…" from the excerpt above. Would the sentence have the same meaning when there would be "that we do not lose sight…"?

Comment: *demands of us that we not lose sight* uses the subjunctive. Likewise, *demands of us that we not be hasty*, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a simple sentence, the *[do insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)* would be required for negation:

> *We lose sight of the facts.*
>   *We **do** not lose sight of the facts.*

In an independent clause of a complex sentence, the *[do insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)* would still be required for negation:

> *We **do** not lose sight of the facts, because the Holocaust demands it.*

In the subordinate clause complementing *demands*, the *[do insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)* becomes optional:

> *The Holocaust demands that we [do] not lose sight of the facts.*

Comment: I see this answer as true, but I am curious. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The `do` is not required here. If this were a positive sentence, do could be used to provide emphasis. But since this is a negative sentence, including `do` here would be wrong.

Comment: **Why** is it wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am a little bit puzzled. If I am right the author wants to say that we must not lose the sight of the fact that holocaust was a singular event. The form of negative statement should be "do not  + verb". Why is it not so in that case?

Comment: the _not_ alone is sufficient to make it negative.

Comment: ... That would make _do_ optional, not wrong. There are far more Google hits for "ask that you do not" than for "ask that you not".